# Cisco 2851 Static NAT - Similar Static Entry Already Exists

Tags: cisco, nat, ip-forwarding-table

I have a Cisco 2851 with NAT configured as so:

```
ip nat inside source list 111 interface GigabitEthernet0/1 overload
ip nat inside source static 192.168.16.16 64.xxx.xxx.233
ip nat inside source static 192.168.16.2 64.xxx.xxx.245
ip nat inside source static 192.168.16.20 64.xxx.xxx.246
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 64.xxx.xxx.1
```

I need to forward only outside traffic from `64.xxx.xxx.233` to port 81 to the inside host 192.168.16.12, leaving all other ports as above. This command:

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.16.12 81 64.xxx.xxx.233 81
```

results in this error:

```
similar static entry (192.168.16.16 -> 64.xxx.xxx.233) already exists
```

Can give me some direction how to get this single port directed to another host given the above?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to specify ports to avoid overlap:

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.16.12 81 64.xxx.xxx.245 81 extendable 
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.16.2 1723 64.xxx.xxx.245 1723 extendable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the different NAT versions. NAT **inside source** translates **source** addresses packets originating on the **inside**, and it maintains tables for returning traffic.

If you want to translate addresses from outside which are destined to the inside, you need to use **inside destination** NAT. This version of NAT can also be used to load balance among multiple inside destinations.

[Cisco IOS Network Address Translation Overview](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/tk648/tk361/tk438/technologies_white_paper09186a0080091cb9.html):

> **Enabling translation of inside destination addresses**
>
> ```
> ip nat inside destination { list <acl> pool <name> | static <global-ip> <local-ip> }
> ```
>
> This command is similar to the source translation command. For dynamic
>   destination translation to make any sense, the pool should be a
>   rotary-type pool.

**Edit:**

Since the outside address is already in the NAT tables with a different rule, you will not be able to have a different translation for it since a lookup of the address will only return one of the table entries.

Comment: Still won't work. It's either 1:1 NAT, or PAT -- I've tried this for *years*. You cannot do both at the same time, with the same address. (using the interface's address is the only exception) (Note: you *can* get into the running-config, but it'll never be stable)

Comment: I didn't see the same address; I was looking at the inside addresses.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your time to help me.  My solution thus far is specifying ports to avoid overlap.  `ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.16.12 81 64.xxx.xxx.245 81 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.16.2 1723 64.xxx.xxx.245 1723 extendable`